# How adding more links on the extension page action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension page action that works only in a specific domain, can I add more than one link to the page action? My background.js is this.

it is possible to add more links in background.html for the extension page action?

//background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([ 
{
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: { urlContains: 'www.exemple.com' },
 })
],
actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
}
]);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can register a page action for multiple sites by adding multiple [`PageStateMatcher`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher)s to the list of `conditions`.

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { hostSuffix: 'example.com' }
                }),
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { hostSuffix: 'example.net' }
                }),
            ],
            actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
       }]);
    });
});
```

Note: I replaced [`urlContains`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#property-UrlFilter-urlContains) with [`hostSuffix`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#property-UrlFilter-hostSuffix) because you wanted to show the page action on certain domains, not on all pages whose URL contain the website's host (e.g. you probably don't want to match `http://localhost/path/containing/www.example.com`). See the documentation of the [`UrlFilter` type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter) for more ways to match pages.

Comment: Thank you helped a lot, sorry for my bad English I am Brazilian.

Comment: @WeillerJayceon No problem. As long as we can understand each other, you'll be fine. [If you think that an answer has solved your question, click on the green checkmark at the left of an answer to mark it as "accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions you can match multiple domains with a single rule.

For example the following matches any Google search page in every country.

```
pageUrl: { urlMatches: '^(www\.)?(google.).*\/search\?', schemes: ['https'] },
```